# Effect of particle size on yield of copper acetylide

Tags: experimental-chemistry, reference-request, organometallic-compounds, precipitation

To avoid pure trial and error, I need some examples of experiments already done with (possibly ammoniacal) aqueous solutions, particles/precipitates of copper (both oxidation states) salts, and acetylene gas.

Since sensitively dependent reactions are often misreported, be sure to provide enough experimental details. No need to interpret anything, just pieces of information are OK.